# Getting listings style to show Spanish accents like these: É é

Tags: listings, unicode, spanish, listingsutf8

So I'm trying to include a Literate Haskell (`.lhs`) code into my Latex thesis, but I'm having some trouble with the encoding of the listings style.

This is how my `test.lhs` files looks like, which I include into my `.tex` using `\input{test.lhs}`

```
This acénto is displayed properly

\begin{code}
import System.IO
-- Thís one is nót.
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Anothér one"
\end{code}

This óne is okay.
```

The [Haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Literate_programming#Listings_package) says that I could use the listings package to format the `code` environment using one of these styles.

The first one is rather simple. It works okay, but isn't very pretty.

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{code}{\lstset{language=Haskell,basicstyle=\small}}{}
```

Then it says that the following settings are the most satisfying way to format the environment.

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstloadlanguages{Haskell}
\lstnewenvironment{code}
    {\lstset{}%
      \csname lst@SetFirstLabel\endcsname}
    {\csname lst@SaveFirstLabel\endcsname}
    \lstset{
      basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
      flexiblecolumns=false,
      basewidth={0.5em,0.45em},
      literate={+}{{$+$}}1 {/}{{$/$}}1 {*}{{$*$}}1 {=}{{$=$}}1
               {>}{{$>$}}1 {<}{{$<$}}1 {\\}{{$\lambda$}}1
               {\\\\}{{\char`\\\char`\\}}1
               {->}{{$\rightarrow$}}2 {>=}{{$\geq$}}2 {<-}{{$\leftarrow$}}2
               {<=}{{$\leq$}}2 {=>}{{$\Rightarrow$}}2 
               {\ .}{{$\circ$}}2 {\ .\ }{{$\circ$}}2
               {>>}{{>>}}2 {>>=}{{>>=}}2
               {|}{{$\mid$}}1               
    }
```

This actually looks great unless I try to use acéntos in my code. If I do it just prints nonsense, and I get the following warning when running pdfLatex

```
Package utf8x Error: MalformedUTF-8sequence
```

I don't see anything obviously wrong in that definition that is preventing me from properly displaying acéntos. What should I do?

Comment: You don't give a full example but it looks like you are using utf8x input encoding. Are you sure you're saving their UTF-8?

Comment: Did you try with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`? The `utf8x` option is not recommended nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out almost immediately after posting.

I just expanded the definition to include a bunch of weird characters.

```
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\lstloadlanguages{Haskell}
\lstnewenvironment{code}
    {\lstset{}%
      \csname lst@SetFirstLabel\endcsname}
    {\csname lst@SaveFirstLabel\endcsname}
    \lstset{
      basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
      flexiblecolumns=false,
      basewidth={0.5em,0.45em},
      literate={+}{{$+$}}1 {/}{{$/$}}1 {*}{{$*$}}1 {=}{{$=$}}1
               {>}{{$>$}}1 {<}{{$<$}}1 {\\}{{$\lambda$}}1
               {\\\\}{{\char`\\\char`\\}}1
               {->}{{$\rightarrow$}}2 {>=}{{$\geq$}}2 {<-}{{$\leftarrow$}}2
               {<=}{{$\leq$}}2 {=>}{{$\Rightarrow$}}2 
               {\ .}{{$\circ$}}2 {\ .\ }{{$\circ$}}2
               {>>}{{>>}}2 {>>=}{{>>=}}2
               {|}{{$\mid$}}1
               {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
               {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
               {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
               {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
               {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
               {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
               {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
               {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
               {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
               {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
               {€}{{\EUR}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1 {λ}{{$\lambda$}}1
    }
```